Execute a stored procedure with output parameters why do they need a null value?
I am making an ERP program for practice from AdventureWorks2019 database in SQL Server and one stored procedure with output parameters didn't run properly unless I specified their value as null, while others similar procedures did not have such an issue. Why? and are the other procedures faulty? What is the textbook way syntactically executing procedures with output parameters? Also any tips please?
drop procedure if exists sohead; 

create procedure sohead
    @BusinessEntityid int,                      
    @customerid int,                        
    @persontype nchar(2) output,        
    @storeid int output,                    
    @orderdate datetime output,             
    @duedate datetime output,               
    @accountnumber nvarchar(15) output,     
    @salespersonid int output,              
    @territoryid int output,            
    @billToAddressid int output,    
    @shipToAddressid int output,    
    @shipMethodid int,  
    @creditcardid int output,   
    @currencyrateid int =null,     
    @subtotal money, 
    @taxamt money,    
    @freight money,     
    --totaldue self generated and computed
    @comment nvarchar(128)  
AS
BEGIN 
    set nocount on;
        begin try
        
            begin transaction
            --@storeid
            
                select @storeid = storeid from sales.customer where CustomerID = @customerid;

            --orderdate 
            SET @orderdate = GETDATE();
            --duedate
            SET @duedate = DATEADD(day, 15, @orderdate);

            --salespersonid
            
            if @storeid IS NULL
                SET @salespersonid = NULL;
            else
                SELECT @salespersonid = SalesPersonID 
                FROM Sales.Store 
                WHERE BusinessEntityID = @storeid;

            --territoryid
            select @territoryid = territoryid from sales.Customer
            where customerid = @customerid;

            --biiltoaddress  AND  shipaddressid
            --;WITH persontypecte AS (
            --      SELECT persontype 
            --      FROM person.Person
            --      WHERE BusinessEntityID = @businessentityid
            --  )
            --select @persontype = persontype from persontypecte
            select @persontype = persontype FROM person.Person
                    WHERE BusinessEntityID = @businessentityid;

            if @persontype = 'SC' 
            BEGIN
                        ;with billshipadd as(
                            SELECT AddressID FROM  
                            person.BusinessEntityAddress

                            where BusinessEntityid = @storeid
    
                        )
                        select   @BILLTOADDRESSID = addressid,@SHIPTOADDRESSID = addressid  from billshipadd; --address GIA 'SC'
            
            END
            ELSE IF @PERSONTYPE = 'IN' 
            BEGIN
                        ;with billshipadd as(
                            SELECT AddressID FROM  
                            person.BusinessEntityAddress

                            where BusinessEntityid = @businessentityid
    
                        )
                        select   @BILLTOADDRESSID = addressid,@SHIPTOADDRESSID = addressid  from billshipadd; --address gia 'IN'
            END;             

            --creditcardid

            select @creditcardid =  CreditCardID from Sales.PersonCreditCard where businessentityid = @BusinessEntityid;

            --accountnumber 

            select @accountnumber = accountnumber from sales.customer where customerid = @customerid;

            --currencyrateid

            --null


            insert into sales.salesorderheader(revisionNumber, orderdate, duedate, shipdate, status,
            onlineorderflag, purchaseordernumber, accountnumber, customerid, salespersonid, territoryid,        
    billtoaddressid, shiptoaddressid, shipmethodid, creditcardid, creditcardapprovalcode,       
    currencyrateid, subtotal, taxamt, freight, comment, rowguid, modifieddate)
            VALUES(
            0,
            @orderdate,
            @duedate,
            null,
            1,
            0,
            null,
            @accountnumber,
            @customerid,
            @salespersonid,
            @territoryid,
            @billToAddressid,
            @shipToAddressid,
            @shipMethodid,
            @creditcardid,
            null, --credit card approval code
            @currencyrateid,
            @subtotal,
            @taxamt,
            @freight,
            --@totaldue, --mono toy
            @comment,
            newid(),
            getdate()
    );

            commit transaction
        end try
        begin catch 
            SELECT
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            rollback transaction;
            throw;
        end catch
end;
                 
exec sohead @businessentityid=1983 , @customerid=30113 ,@shipmethodid= 1, @subtotal =5,
@taxamt =5, @freight = 5, @comment = null,@persontype = null, @storeid = null,@orderdate = null, @duedate = null, @accountnumber= null, @salespersonid= null,
@territoryid = null, @billToAddressid = null, @shipToAddressid=null, @creditcardid = null;

Apparrently this is the right way to execute it
but I thought this was enough:
exec sohead @businessentityid=1983 , @customerid=30113 ,@shipmethodid= 1, @subtotal =5,
@taxamt =5, @freight = 5;


Why use all these output parameters at all? Better to just read back the newly inserted row from the database. You: 1. can ensure the insert was successful with correct data, and 2. get all the data from your attempted output parameters.

Thanks for the feedback, could you pls elaborate further? if i am understanding this right, you mean not make it as one procedure?

OUTPUT parameters are still input parameters; there are input only and input/output parameters, no output only parameters. If you don't assign a default value to the parameter, when it is omitted, then you must provide that parameter when you execute the procedure.
Your OUTPUT parameters don't have a default value, unlike your parameter @currencyrateid for example, so you must provide a value, which can be NULL.

I think you meant to post that comment on the question, @HardCode ?
